# What is the correct or efficient form to write a Makefile when you need two executables that use the same library?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile to compile two programs that include the same .h (also mine), but with my actual Makefile if I type "make" in command line twice in a row, I don't get "bla bla is up to date", it recompile part of the stuff when it's not necessary. Any way to do this in a more efficient form?

### Context

`producer.c` and `consumer.c` #include `random_numbers.h` in order to generate random numbers to its functions.

### My Makefile

```
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -g
LIBS = -lrt -lpthread
HEADER_FILES_DIR = .
INCLUDES = -I $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)
SRCS = e1_producer.c e1_consumer.c $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)/random_num.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.co)
DEPS = $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)/random_num.h


all: e1_producer e1_consumer

random_num.o: random_num.c random_num.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c random_num.c

e1_producer: e1_producer.o random_num.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o producer e1_producer.o random_num.o $(LIBS)

e1_producer.o: e1_producer.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c e1_producer.c $(LIBS)

e1_consumer: e1_consumer.o random_num.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o consumer e1_consumer.o random_num.o $(LIBS)

e1_consumer.o: e1_consumer.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c e1_consumer.c $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm producer consumer *.o
```

### Output after two consecutive "make" in the command line

```
$ make
$ gcc -Wall -g -c e1_producer.c -lrt -lpthread
$ gcc -Wall -g -c random_num.c
$ gcc -Wall -g -o producer e1_producer.o random_num.o -lrt -lpthread
$ gcc -Wall -g -c e1_consumer.c -lrt -lpthread
$ gcc -Wall -g -o consumer e1_consumer.o random_num.o -lrt -lpthread
$ make
gcc -Wall -g -o producer e1_producer.o random_num.o -lrt -lpthread
gcc -Wall -g -o consumer e1_consumer.o random_num.o -lrt -lpthread
```

Why is this happening? When I do the same with another single program the second `$ make` returns me "nothing to do, bla bla is up to date"

Comment: Try removing `$(LIBS)` when creating the .o files.  It's not needed.

Comment: You are breaking rule 2 of the (non-normative but highly recommended) [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/). The rule for `e1_producer` does not produce a file called `e1_producer`, likewise for `e1_consumer`.

Comment: @dbush thanks, I did not considerate that!

Comment: @user657267 that wasn't my main problem but it's good to know, thanks mate

Comment: @S.Buzzoni It is *exactly* your problem but don't take my word for it, try it.